# Seamlessly paint textures for cube map

Tags: texture-painting

I'm creating a deatiled planet so I'd like to create a cubemap of 2k textures for high resolution. How can I seamlessly paint all six textures for each face of the cube? I have the sphere uv unwrapped into a "t" shape. [image]

Comment: How do you plan to paint, in the 3D view? How does your texture look like? You can paint each face and then correct all the visible seams

Comment: Yes 3d texture paint view. How would I go about correcting the seams?